# Is the English word sky a better translation for the Greek word “Ouranios” than heaven in the sermon on the mount?

Tags: matthew

Sky is used in Matthew chapter 5 through chapter 7 instead of heaven by the Bible project for various reasons. Is the translation of the Greek word ouranois Better translated sky and then the word heaven?

See Matt 5:3, 10, 12, 16, 18, 19, 20, 34, 45, 6:1, 9, 10, 20, 26, 7:11, 21.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! Please take the tour to learn about the site: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: We normally need specific verses to deal with in this group. Can you provide specific instances of the BP's translation, or a link to them?

Comment: Your question opens up a huge topic! A few weeks ago, I finished Jonathan Pennington's book, *Heaven and Earth in the Gospel of Matthew*. This 400-page book is derived from his PhD thesis and is extremely well researched but very academic. He points out that the word “heaven” in biblical Hebrew and Aramaic is always written in the plural, “heavens,” while the word “heaven” in old Greek is commonly written in the singular for grammatical reasons. The heavens (plural) refers to 1. the abode of clouds, 2. the abode of stars, and 3. the abode of God. In the Greek singular, it's only the 3rd one.

Answer (score 1):

The instances of οὐρανός (ouranos) = "heaven" in Matt 5-7 can be classified into several types:

1. "kingdom of heaven" as per Matt 5:3, 10, 19, 20, etc
2. "Father in heaven" as per Matt 5:16, 34, 45, 6:1, 9, 10, etc
3. heaven as the destiny of the saints as per Matt 5:12, 6:20, etc
4. "Birds of the sky" or "Birds of air" as per Matt 6:26.
5. "heaven and earth" as per Matt 5:18. [This clearly alludes to Gen 1:1.]

In only two of these numerous instances in Matt 5-7 of οὐρανός (ouranos) would "sky" or "air" be appropriate, namely the last two, #4, & #5 above.  All the other make no sense to translate, "kingdom of the sky" and "Our Father in the sky".

Answer (score 1):

**Is the English word *sky* a better translation for the Greek word “Ouranios” than *heaven* in the sermon on the mount?**

I'll attempt an in-depth answer to add to Dottard's. However, the sort answer is: **no**.

οὐράνιος, ον (Ouranois) basically means “of or in heaven” in Greek. In the [Englishman's Concordance](https://biblehub.com/greek/ouranois_3772.htm) οὐρανοῖς (ouranois) has 38 Occurrences all of which are translated as heaven(s) in the NAS, KJV, and INT.

Now, **ouranois comes from the word** οὐρανός, οῦ, ὁ **ouranos** which has many different forms and can have a broader meaning. In the New Testament, these often refer to “the dwelling place of God”, the “abode of angels”, and a “place of blessedness” for believers. But it can also mean literally “the sky or the atmosphere.”

Let's look at both of the words to see the difference.

**[Strong's Concordance](https://biblehub.com/greek/3770.htm)**

**ouranios: of or in heaven**
**Original Word:** οὐράνιος, ον
**Part of Speech:** Adjective
**Transliteration:** ouranios
**Phonetic Spelling:** (oo-ran'-ee-os)
**Definition:** of or in heaven
**Usage:** in heaven, belonging to heaven, heavenly, from heaven.

**[Strong's Concordance](https://biblehub.com/greek/3772.htm)**

**ouranos: heaven**
**Original Word:** οὐρανός, οῦ, ὁ
**Part of Speech:** Noun, Masculine
**Transliteration:** ouranos
**Phonetic Spelling:** (oo-ran-os')
**Definition:** heaven
**Usage:** heaven, (a) the visible heavens: the atmosphere, the sky, the starry heavens, (b) the spiritual heavens.

All of the following verses use some form of ouranos:

**Referring to the Dwelling Place of God:**

- Matthew 5:16: Let your light so shine before men, that they may see
  your good works and glorify your **Father in heaven** (ouranois).
- Matthew 6:9: "In this manner, therefore, pray: **Our Father in heaven** (ouranois), Hallowed be Your name."

**Describing the Abode of Angels:**

- Matthew 18:10: “Take heed that you do not despise one of these little
  ones, for I say to you that **in heaven** (ouranois) **their angels** always see the
  face of My Father who is in **heaven** (ouranois).
- Luke 2:13-14: And suddenly there was with the **angel a multitude of
  the heavenly** (ouraniou) **host**  praising God and saying: 14 “Glory to God in the highest, And on earth peace, goodwill toward men!”

**Place of Blessedness:**

- Matthew 5:12: Rejoice and be exceedingly glad, for **great is your
  reward in heaven** (ouranois), for so they persecuted the prophets who were before
  you.
- Matthew 19:21: Jesus said to him, “If you want to be perfect, go,
  sell what you have and give to the poor, and you will have **treasure
  in heaven** (ouranois); and come, follow Me.”

**Referring to the Literal Sky or Atmosphere:**

- Matthew 6:26: Look at the birds of the **air** (ouranou, οὐρανοῦ), for they neither sow nor
  reap nor gather into barns; yet your **heavenly** (ouranios) Father feeds them. Are
  you not of more value than they?
- Matthew 16:2-3: He answered and said to them, “When it is evening you
  say, ‘It will be fair weather, for the **sky** (ouranos, οὐρανὸς) is red’; 3 and in the
  morning, ‘It will be foul weather today, for the **sky** (ouranos, οὐρανὸς) is red and
  threatening.’ Hypocrites! You know how to discern the face of the
  **sky** (ouranou, οὐρανοῦ), but you cannot discern the signs of the times.

The provided examples are to illustrate how both "ouranios" and other forms of "ouranos" are employed in different contexts to convey distinct meanings.

**Conclusion:** You'll notice that in the above examples, the Greek changes when referring to the sky and the air. Ouranos is a word with many different forms so we have to be careful not to think that all of them mean *exactly* the same thing. **In summary, the analysis provides evidence that "ouranios" is more accurately translated as "heavenly" or "heaven" rather than "sky".**

[Forms and Transliterations](https://biblehub.com/greek/3772.htm)

```
  ουρανε ουρανέ οὐρανέ ουρανο΄ν ουρανοι ουρανοί οὐρανοί οὐρανοὶ ουρανοις ουρανοίς οὐρανοις οὐρανοῖς ουρανον ουρανόν οὐρανόν οὐρανὸν ουρανος ουρανός οὐρανός οὐρανὸς ουρανου ουρανού οὐρανοῦ ουρανους ουρανούς οὐρανούς οὐρανοὺς ουρανω ουρανώ ούρανώ οὐρανῷ οὐρανῳ ουρανων ουρανών οὐρανῶν 

  ourane ourané ourano ouranō ouranoi ouranoí ouranoì ouranôi ouranōi ouranō̂i ouranois ouranoîs ouranon ouranón ouranòn ouranôn ouranōn ouranō̂n ouranos ouranós ouranòs ouranou ouranoû ouranous ouranoús ouranoùs
```